# what jQuery event expression mean when it has a dot in it

Tags: jquery, events

I was reading through a jQuery plugin and found a weird event(at lease to me) expression like following:

```
$(this).find('ul:first').bind('scroll.sticky', function(e) {
    //some code;
});
```

The question is what does ".sticky" mean? I only know the "scroll" part.
I tried to search jQuery document but didn't found anything. Can you point me the right page?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Those are *namespaced events*.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: The link is outdated. Site maybe moved to https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/